# Synonymizations for [graphics-editing] before pumpkinization happens

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

[graphics-design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-design) and synonomized [graphic-design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphic-design) had 20-odd questions and the tag was undefined.

Since graphic design isn't really on-topic, I looked at the associated questions.  Most were just unrelated decoration, so I cleaned them up.

Only three remained, one of which was closed as a duplicated of a closed question.  These were about graphics editing rather than graphic design.  Since there were only a couple, I went ahead and retagged those with the existing but little-used [graphics-editing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-editing) tag.

The deprecated [graphics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics) tag has over 400 questions, and I suspect many of them can be retagged with [graphics-editing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-editing).  [graphics-editing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-editing) was also undefined, so I drafted a wiki and wiki excerpt.

Which brings me to this question.  [graphics-design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-design) has two followers and is now empty, so it will disappear in a day.  Some number of people relate to the term "graphic-design" rather than "graphics editing" (given the difference in past tag choice).  Suggestion: while they still exist, synonomize [graphics-design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-design) and [graphic-design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphic-design) with [graphics-editing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-editing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[graphics-design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-design) and [graphic-design](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphic-design) have been synonymised with [graphics-editing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics-editing).

[graphics](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/graphics) needs to be dealt with separately, which I think is what you are suggesting, as it is too vague and probably attached to many unrelated subjects.